# Understand behavior of __delete__ in descriptor with multi-variable assignment on one line

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties

This is a descriptor created to (partially) emulate the property class in python, but in a lazy fashion.

```
# non useful methods and implementations get abstracted away
class LazyProperty(object):
    def __init__(self, fget=None):
        self.fget = fget

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        result = obj.__dict__[self.fget.__name__] = self.fget(obj)
        return result

    def __delete__(self, obj):
        pass
```

Creating another class and decorate the method within this newly defined class with `LazyProperty` as the follow

```
class MyClass:
    @LazyProperty
    def x(self):
        print("called once")
        return 5


my_class = MyClass()
my_class.x
my_class.x
```

Run this code, I was expecting `function x` in `MyClass` would only be called **once**, but in fact it gets called **twice**. If comment out the `__delete__` method from the `LazyProperty` and run it again, then things went back to match the expectation -- `function x` gets called only once. The exact same behavior has been found when replacing `__delete__` with `__set__`. I feel there is some mechanism being running under the hood which causes this issue, probably due to how I assigning the variables, does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The presence of a `__set__` or `__delete__` method makes a descriptor a *data descriptor*. Data descriptors take priority over instance `__dict__` entries, so your descriptor's `__get__` is called even if a previous call has already cached a value in the instance dict.

Your `__get__` does not correctly handle the case where the value has already been computed. It unconditionally recomputes the value every time it is called.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you be a bit specific on how to handle the case where value has been computed, if cache with `__dict__` is not enough.

Comment: @GabrielChu: Return the cached value.